# Tic-Tac-Toe I can't setBounds of the x button

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jbutton

In my Tic-Tac-Toe game, I have painted the lines and I am now trying to put in the buttons.  The first button I am trying to put in, I am trying to set the bounds of, and It doesn't set the bounds.  It just fills the whole screen.  How do I get `button` to only be in the top right square?

```
public class Project extends JFrame{

static JButton button = new JButton("");
static JButton button2 = new JButton("");
static JButton button3 = new JButton("");
static JButton button4 = new JButton("");
static JButton button5 = new JButton("");
static JButton button6 = new JButton("");
static JButton button7 = new JButton("");
static JButton button8 = new JButton("");
static JButton button9 = new JButton("");


    public Project(){
        setSize(1000, 750);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(100, 100, 100, 400);
        Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Float(200, 100, 200, 400);
        Line2D line3 = new Line2D.Float(0, 200, 300, 200);
        Line2D line4 = new Line2D.Float(0, 300, 300, 300);
        g2.draw(line);
        g2.draw(line2);
        g2.draw(line3);
        g2.draw(line4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Project t = new Project();
        t.setVisible(true);
        button.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
        t.add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to use [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Project class extends JFrame, and the JFrame contentPane, the JFrame container that accepts new components, uses BorderLayout by default. When you add a component to a BorderLayout-using container without specifying where the component goes, it is by default added to the BorderLayout.CENTER position, effectively filling up your GUI. Several options exist to solve your dilemma:

- Use a GridLayout as suggested by PM77-1. This way a 3x3 grid will hold all 9 buttons in equal sized cells, filling up the container.
- Not using buttons and ActionListeners at all, but rather using a MouseListenerListener to check where a button press has occurred, deciding if its an empty cell, and acting accordingly.

Comment: you reminded me that I wasn't using a `null` layout by talking about the `borderLayout`.  I should've seen that.  Thank you.

Comment: @cade: about the worst thing you can do in this situation is to use a null layout. While they might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms different from the original one.... You've already got a decent and easy layout manager that you can use,... use it.